# Tensorflow lite audio classification model support rtsp voice?

Tags: flutter, audio, camera, tflite

I use [easy_onvif](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_onvif): ^2.1.3+9 for get RTSP Link from cctv and play it with [flutter_vlc_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player).

i want to add audio classification to cctv by mobile application.
and i found [TensorFlowLite example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/audio_classification/android) .
this TensorFlowLite example, worked perfectly but use mobile microphone to classification.

can i use cctv audio in this TensorFlowLite project ?

In this example AudioClassification Class.

```kotlin
interface AudioClassificationListener {
    fun onError(error: String)
    fun onResult(results: List<Category>, inferenceTime: Long)
}

class AudioClassificationHelper(
    val context: Context,
    val listener: AudioClassificationListener,
    var currentModel: String = YAMNET_MODEL,
    var classificationThreshold: Float = DISPLAY_THRESHOLD,
    var overlap: Float = DEFAULT_OVERLAP_VALUE,
    var numOfResults: Int = DEFAULT_NUM_OF_RESULTS,
    var currentDelegate: Int = 0,
    var numThreads: Int = 2
) {
    private lateinit var classifier: AudioClassifier
    private lateinit var tensorAudio: TensorAudio
    private lateinit var recorder: AudioRecord
    private lateinit var executor: ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

    private val classifyRunnable = Runnable {
        classifyAudio()
    }

    init {
        initClassifier()
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun initClassifier() {
        // Set general detection options, e.g. number of used threads
        val baseOptionsBuilder = BaseOptions.builder()
            .setNumThreads(numThreads)

        // Use the specified hardware for running the model. Default to CPU.
        // Possible to also use a GPU delegate, but this requires that the classifier be created
        // on the same thread that is using the classifier, which is outside of the scope of this
        // sample's design.
        when (currentDelegate) {
            DELEGATE_CPU -> {
                // Default
            }
            DELEGATE_NNAPI -> {
                baseOptionsBuilder.useNnapi()
            }
        }

        // Configures a set of parameters for the classifier and what results will be returned.
        val options = AudioClassifier.AudioClassifierOptions.builder()
            .setScoreThreshold(classificationThreshold)
            .setMaxResults(numOfResults)
            .setBaseOptions(baseOptionsBuilder.build())
            .build()

        try {
            // Create the classifier and required supporting objects
            classifier = AudioClassifier.createFromFileAndOptions(context, currentModel, options)
            tensorAudio = classifier.createInputTensorAudio()
            recorder = classifier.createAudioRecord()
            startAudioClassification()
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            listener.onError(
                "Audio Classifier failed to initialize. See error logs for details"
            )

            Log.e("AudioClassification", "TFLite failed to load with error: " + e.message)
        }
    }

    fun startAudioClassification() {
        if (recorder.recordingState == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) {
            return
        }

        recorder.startRecording()
        executor = ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)

        // Each model will expect a specific audio recording length. This formula calculates that
        // length using the input buffer size and tensor format sample rate.
        // For example, YAMNET expects 0.975 second length recordings.
        // This needs to be in milliseconds to avoid the required Long value dropping decimals.
        val lengthInMilliSeconds = ((classifier.requiredInputBufferSize * 1.0f) /
                classifier.requiredTensorAudioFormat.sampleRate) * 1000

        val interval = (lengthInMilliSeconds * (1 - overlap)).toLong()

        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            classifyRunnable,
            0,
            interval,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    }

    private fun classifyAudio() {
        tensorAudio.load(recorder)
        var inferenceTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
        val output = classifier.classify(tensorAudio)
        inferenceTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - inferenceTime
        val results = output[0].categories
        listener.onResult(results, inferenceTime)
    }
    fun stopAudioClassification() {
        recorder.stop()
        executor.shutdownNow()
    }

    companion object {
        const val DELEGATE_CPU = 0
        const val DELEGATE_NNAPI = 1
        const val DISPLAY_THRESHOLD = 0.1f
        const val DEFAULT_NUM_OF_RESULTS = 2
        const val DEFAULT_OVERLAP_VALUE = 0.5f
        const val YAMNET_MODEL = "yamnet.tflite"
        const val SPEECH_COMMAND_MODEL = "speech.tflite"
    }
}
```

i haven't any idea!

can someone help me?
Thanks in Advance!